# Rails server fails to start in docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

When I start my container via `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 mycontainer`, `rails s` hangs and doesn't listen to the port.

It gets as far as `starning in development http://0.0.0.0:3000` but then nothing else happens.

Container log

```
=> Booting Thin

=> Rails 6.0.3.4 application starting in development http://0.0.0.0:3000

=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/active_utils-3.2.0/lib/active_utils/connection.rb:14: warning: previous definition of CA_FILE was here
```

If I start the container from docker dashboard via `run` button of the image then it gets to `listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, ctrl+c to stop` and I'm able to access it through localhost:3000

Container log

```
=> Booting Thin

=> Rails 6.0.3.4 application starting in development http://0.0.0.0:3000

=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/active_utils-3.2.0/lib/active_utils/connection.rb:14: warning: previous definition of CA_FILE was here

2021-03-26 14:19:08 +0000 Thin web server (v1.8.0 codename Possessed Pickle)

2021-03-26 14:19:08 +0000 Maximum connections set to 1024


2021-03-26 14:19:08 +0000 Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Any ideas what's the difference between starting containers via dashboard and docker run?

How can I get docker run to work correctly with rails s?

Comment: `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 mycontainer` runs as a daemon (in background). Please run `docker ps` and check whether rails container is running. If you still dont see its running, then use `docker run-p 3000:3000 mycontainer` And update the question with errors you see here.

Comment: There are no errors and same thing happens without `-d`. The container is running but it is `rails s` fails to listen to the port.